# Turn off notification category of an App using ADB Shell

Tags: android, shell, adb

I'm writing a **shell script** that turns off a notification category from specific applications. some built-in apps doesn't allow to turn off some of their notification without **root** access. for example `com.google.android.dialer` doesn't allow to turn off **Google Play service availability**. I hope this can do via `adb shell`.

first, I tried this command:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys notification | egrep Phone
  mDefaultPhoneApp=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.dialer/com.android.incallui.InCallServiceImpl}
```

and if I filter `phone`:

```
$ adb shell dumpsys notification | egrep phone
  NotificationChannel{mId='phone_ongoing_call', ...}
  NotificationChannel{mId='phone_incoming_call', ...}
  NotificationChannel{mId='phone_low_priority', ...}
  NotificationChannel{mId='phone_voicemail_account', ...}
  NotificationChannel{mId='phone_missed_call', ...}
  NotificationChannel{mId='phone_default', ...}
```

So is there any command for disable/enable specific notification for a application via `adb shell`?

Comment: Have you succeeded?

Comment: I don't think it's possible yet, would love to be proven wrong though! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239549294

Comment: I'm also wanting to disable the "Google Play service availability" notification. I put it on Google's issue tracker. Hopefully they will do something about it, because they usually seem to be good about letting the user disable their apps. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/260925080

Comment: I found out how to disable notifications for the dialer app. Replace the "Phone" app with another one such as "Simple Dialer" and then the system settings will let you disable the notifications for the built in dialer app! :D